# Jquery - Calling a function within a namespace

Tags: jquery, function, namespaces

How do I call a regular function in a namespace

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Timeline.init();
  Timeline.highlight_arrow();
  Timeline.arrows();

});

Timeline.arrows = (function() {
    function display_arrows(pos) {
    }
}());
```

I am tring to call dislay_arrows from inside Timeline.arrows I tried Timeline.arrows.display_arrows() does it need to be a public method?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement it like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ncphx/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function NS_TimeLine(){

        this.init = function(){
         alert("init");   
        }

        this.highlight_arrow = function(){
         alert("init");   
        }

    }                      

var TimeLine = new NS_TimeLine();
TimeLine.init();

});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem, you just need to pass your function back out of the immediately executed function:

```
Timeline.arrows = (function() {
    return function display_arrows(pos) {
        //'arrows' implementation here'
    }
}());
```

Working demo: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iyafop/1/edit)

This way, the /result/ of your `(function() { /*...*/}())` is the `display_arrows` function, so that will be set against the `arrows` property on `Timeline`.

I'm assuming that you have declared a `Timeline` object someone prior to using it as well.